# Do you physically need a license to drive in the US?

Tags: usa, legal, car-rentals, us-citizens

I am a US citizen and rent a lot. Sometimes, owing to some reasons, I forget to take my driver's license with me.

Do you need the *actual* driver's license to drive in the US? I know my license number, expiration and SSN by memory. What happens if I get pulled over but I don't actually *have* my license card on me?

Comment: Legality aside, don't car rental places ask to see your license?

Comment: @cpast the guy rented a car with his license, then went to his place.. then later went out again but this time he forgot the license. I guess This is the scenario the OP have in mind.

Answer (score 7):

This is a matter of state law, so the answer will vary by state; there is not  a single answer for "the US".  [This article](http://traffic.findlaw.com/traffic-tickets/driving-without-a-valid-driver-s-license.html) describes some of the possibilities and links to the relevant state laws.

For example, in my home state of Colorado, [CRS 42-2-101 (2)](http://www.lexisnexis.com/hottopics/colorado?source=COLO;CODE&tocpath=1WO42FJSPQ3YJ8MUW,2TSCTE0PRO6HSAIGO,3XI1LKBIP3LO6XWOM;14JL8PMOQ4KFJSTX3,2IKW8OXJPGG369SS9,3IIJKC9RCBS0OAKXN;1CTUCPM0W4PFJW419,2IK86A2KPGWFA9SSX,38NJK4V6HBSW88D5O;1G8L2KPOQCA9S4FIN,2JKGKUHBS4ZL75O4J,3L8PMOQ4KFJSTX3IK&shortheader=no) states that you may not drive unless you have your driver's license in your "immediate possession".  However, subsection (6) provides that if you are charged with a violation of this law, and you appear in court with your license, the charge will be dismissed.  But it is not sufficient to just be able to tell a police officer your license number or other identifying information - by law, you would still get a ticket, and have to go to court to clear it.

As you mentioned renting: Many (if not all) rental companies will refuse to rent to you if you cannot produce your physical driver's license.  This is likely to be true as a matter of company policy, regardless of whether the relevant state law would allow you to drive without the license.

Answer (score 6):

Depending in the state, the connectivity of the computer in the trooper's car, and the mood and/or ticket quota status of the trooper, you might be ok just by knowing your details. I left my wallet at home once, in my area drivers have 72 hours to produce so I went home, then to the police station and produced it. The desk officer called the issuing officer who said just make a copy of the license and he will cancel the ticket when he gets back. I heard all this over the open radio. "Cancel" in my jurisdiction means it never existed.

In my particular case it was quite beneficial to not have my license as the guy completely forgot to write up the rolling stop that he initially pulled me over for.

However, in your example you will be far away from home, so you can't just go and get it.

Also, there's no car rental company on the continent that will give you the keys without also seeing an original, valid license and supporting documentation from a Vienna Convention country, so whatever the local police think isn't relevant. As you will not have a car you will not be stopped for any traffic violations.

Comment: I think cops can check details over the radio, so I'm not sure connectivity of the computer matters that much.

Comment: Also, strictly speaking I think you meant *Geneva* Convention or Inter-American Convention country, since those are what allow foreign drivers to operate in the US (the US and Canada are not actually party to the Vienna Convention on Road Traffic).

Comment: The 1968 Vienna Convention on Road Traffic is more recent, and easier to find. Search for "Geneva Convention" and you get the one about the rules of war. Driving isn't quite that bad yet.

Comment: Cops can check over the radio, but it takes a lot more effort. If he can check your details easily, he probably will. If dispatch is busy, you will simply get a ticket for failing to produce. It is NOT their job to look up your details just because you forgot the card.

Comment: Re: conventions, the Vienna Convention is more recent but is not actually relevant in the US, because the US is not a party to the Vienna Convention. Nor is Canada. Nor Australia. Nor the Dominican Republic. Etc. All their licenses are valid in the US, though. OTOH, licenses from countries like Pakistan which *are* party to the Vienna Convention but *not* the Geneva Convention aren't valid in the US, unless there's a special bilateral agreement. So while it's easier to find the Vienna Convention, it's about as relevant to US driving as the laws of war.

Comment: This is the exception, not the rule. If you don't have your license when pulled over, you should expect a ticket.

Comment: well said. By law you're required to have it with you. If the cop pulling you over is nice, he may overlook you not being able to show it on demand, but he certainly doesn't have to and if he's under pressure to fill his ticket quota for the month he's going to ticket you for sure.

Comment: @jwenting By what law, in what state? The very answer you're commenting on says that the law (in some unstated place) says you must either have your license with you or show it at a police station within 72hrs.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Then you have some states, or at least one, where it is true that the law says both that you must have your license with you and that you cannot be convicted if you produce your license at the police station within 48 hours. The state in this case is [New Hampshire](https://law.justia.com/codes/new-hampshire/2015/title-xxi/chapter-263/section-263-2/): "Every person...shall have his driver's license upon his person.... No person...shall be convicted if, within...48 hours, he produces in the office of the arresting officer evidence that he held a valid driver's license...."

Comment: Every state law is different, however it is important in general to understand that Police Officers are not Judges. A police officer can write you a ticket for any issue, you should not argue with that decision. You may not feel the ticket is 'just' or 'valid'. That is why you go before a Judge to get Justice. Judges have the legal right to fine tune how laws are applied.